# what is the "right" way to do form validation with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am doing some form validation on a project with javascript. what im doing works but it seems like there might be a better way to do it.  here is an example of what i have.

```
onkeypress="return keyNumOnly(event)"
function keyNumOnly(key)
{//this allows numbers and decimals.   
    var keychar;
    var numcheck;
    var keynum;
    if(window.event) // IE
        {
            keynum = key.keyCode;
        }     
    else if(key.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        {
            keynum = key.which;
        }
    if (keynum==8)
        {
            return true;
        }
    keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
    numcheck = /\d/;
    if (keychar== ".")
        {
            return true;    
        }
    return numcheck.test(keychar);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cleanup:

```
someTextbox.onkeypress = function(event) { // you can pass a function directly
    var event    = event || window.event, 
        // this means: event or window.event if event does not exist

        keynum   = event.keyCode || event.which,
        // event.keyCode or event.which otherwise

        keychar  = String.fromCharCode(keynum),

        numcheck = /\d/;


    if(/\t|\./.test(keychar)) {
        // checking for dot or tab using a regexp: \t is tab, | means 'or', \. is dot
        return true;
    }


    return numcheck.test(keychar);
}
```

Comment: thank you.  i am pretty new so i know a lot of my code could use some cleaning up.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a pre-packaged solution to do form validation. For example, if you can use jQuery the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) does a great job of validating forms - both live validation (like it looks like you are doing) as well as validation prior to a 'submit' event.

Comment: thanks justin.  i am using jquery in other parts of my project so i will have to look up how to implement that.  Yes we are doing live validation for this part.  the on submit validation will be done on the server.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree that you need to do server-side validation as well. I was just trying to point out some of the functionality of  this plugin. Anyway, good luck! :)

Comment: do you think you give give me a couple lines of example jquery code that you have used for validation?

Answer (score 0):

Form valiation (e.g. against regexes) is part of HTML5, and hence can soon be done by the browser itself.

[Dive into HTML5 explains how](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/forms.html#validation)

Comment: Good info but this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: that is some very interesting information.  but the validation im doing is pretty specific.  like i want only numbers plus some special characters like #.-() for example.